# Custom Class wc_add_notice - Wordpress - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

Hello I have this code that creates a wordpress session message.

```
wc_add_notice(__('My mensaje!', 'mensajeper'), 'error');
```

This creates a message after reloading the page with the class

```
woocommerce-error
```

So far we are doing fine.
How to add a custom class to this message for example

```
woocommerce-error-messageper
```

I am working with wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce doesn't offer a hook to change that. so you will need to overwrite the woocommerce template.

You need to copy the code from the error notice template here
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/notices/error.php

and create the same file in ACTIVE-THEME-FOLDER/woocommerce/notices/error.php

with the class change.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! $notices ) {
    return;
}

?>
<ul class="woocommerce-error woocommerce-error-messageper" role="alert">
    <?php foreach ( $notices as $notice ) : ?>
        <li<?php echo wc_get_notice_data_attr( $notice ); ?>>
            <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```